# Polymorphic types in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, polymorphism, polymorphic-functions

I came across this function

```
iter p f x = if (p x) then x else (iter p f (f x))
```

and I thought I'd give a go at defining the polymorphic types myself to understand the concept.

My thought was the following:

The function takes 3 parameters, so we have **`t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> T`**

1. `p` is being used inside the if condition so it must return a `bool`, therefore `t1 = a -> Bool`
2. `f` is also the same type as `p` because it is passed as an argument in the else block, therefore `t2 = a -> Bool`
3. x is being used inside the if condition so it must return a bool, therefore `t1 = a -> Bool`

But when i checked the type in the ghci, the type they gave me was

`iter :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> t) -> t -> t`

Can someone please explain the reasoning behind this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The function takes 3 parameters, so we have t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> T

This is correct as a starting point.

> p is being used inside the if condition so it must return a bool, therefore t1 = a -> Bool

Correct.

> f is also the same type as p because it is passed as an argument in the else block, therefore t2 = a -> Bool

Incorrect. `f` is never used in the same way as `p`. In the else block `f` is being applied to `x` and the result passed as the last argument to `iter`. From that we know `f x` must be the same type as `x` so `f :: a -> a`.

> x is being used inside the if condition so it must return a bool, therefore t1 = a -> Bool

Incorrect. In the if condition `x` is being used only as an argument to `p`. You established above `p :: a -> Bool`. Therefore `x :: a`.

> But when i checked the type in the ghci, the type they gave me was
>
> iter :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> t) -> t -> t

Correct. You could also write this replacing `t` with `a` to be consistent in the notation - we used `a` above:

```
iter :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Comment: I see, so every time when two parameters are being applied to one another inside the function, both parameters must be of the same type? For example, `f x` was passed in the else, that means `f` and `x` must be the same type in order to call the `iter` function?

Comment: No, not in general. It's a special case here since we know that the type of `f x` must be the same as `x`. We know that because both are passed as the third argument to `iter`. Edit: sorry, misread, I should have said No, not at all :) `f :: a -> a` and `x :: a` so they are not the same type at all. `f` is a function that must *return* `a` and we are passing it `x :: a` as an argument thus `f :: a -> a`

Comment: Thank you, I really love yours and Willem's answers. They both cleared so much for me. Cant choose which one as accepted. But Ill give you this one as for my last question I accepted his :)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Let's evaluate it again:

```
iter p f x = if (p x) then x else (iter p f (f x))
```

`iter` takes three parameters (well technically speaking every function takes one parameter, but let's skip the details). So it has indeed a type `t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> t`.

Now in the `if`-`then`-`else` statement, we see `(p x)` this means that `p x` has to evaluate to a boolean. So that means that:

```
t1 ~ t3 -> Bool
```

Next we see `x` in the `then` statement. This may strike as non-important, but it is: it means that the output type `t` is the same as that of `t3`, so:

```
t3 ~ t
```

Now that means we already derived that `iter` has the type:

```
iter :: (t3 -> Bool) -> t2 -> t3 -> t3
```

Now we see in the `else` statement the call:

```
iter p f (f x)
```

So that means that `f` is a function `f :: t4 -> t5`. Since it takes `x` as input, its input type should be `t3`, and since the result of `(f x)` is passed to an `iter` function (that is ***not* per se the same "grounded" `iter`** function). So we have to inspect the call:

```
iter :: (u3 -> Bool) -> u2 -> u3 -> u3  -- call
```

Now since we call it with `iter p f (f x)` we definitely know that `u3 ~ t3`: because `p` has type `t3 -> Bool`. So it grounds further to:

```
iter :: (t3 -> Bool) -> u2 -> t3 -> t3  -- call
```

Sine `(f x)` is used as third argument, we know that the type of the result of `f x` should be `t3` as well. So `f` has type `f :: t3 -> t3`. So we conclude that iter has the type:

```
iter :: (t3 -> Bool) -> (t3 -> t3) -> t3 -> t3
```